# How to create a random string everytime a test runs in karate dsl

Tags: dsl, karate

The json request I am sending is:

```
Given url applicationURL

And path 'applications'

And header Authorization = subscribeToken

And request:

    {
      "throttlingTier": "Unlimited",
      "description": "sample app description",
      "name": "TestbyKarate",
      "callbackUrl": "https:/apistore-dev-dev-a878-14-ams10-nonp.qcpaws.qantas.com.au/callback"
    }

When method post

Then status 201

* def applicationId = response.applicationId

* print 'applicationId is ', applicationId
```

I am sending the name in my request as `TestbyKarate` but I want to send a unique value every time my test runs.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you please read the docs once. It will really benefit you.

https://github.com/intuit/karate#commonly-needed-utilities

So in the `Background` or common feature, you have:

```
* def now = function(){ return java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis() }
```

Then you can do this:

```
* def name = 'Test-' + now()
* request { name: '#(name)' }
```

Comment: Peter can you tell how do we print request body? to confirm whats going in the request ? * print request does not work

Comment: @Gauravkhurana maybe you are looking for `karate.prevRequest` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62510900/143475

Comment: @PeterThomas sir can you add ready to use variables that like generate email, string, or fullName like postman, it will really help us

Comment: @roudlek read the docs please: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#commonly-needed-utilities

Answer (score 0):

check below example

Feature: Create User Name

Scenario: UserName with unique Name

- def getDate =
  """
  function(){ return java.lang.System.nanoTime() }
  """

  - def time = getDate()
  - def userName = 'createUser' + time + '_Test'